# NPM configure error due to Homebrew Python Install

Tags: npm, homebrew, conda

I recently installed `conda` via Homebrew on my machine and I noticed that every time I run `npm install` commands, npm is triggering an error that references a python command from my conda directory, but the install finished with success. Has anyone faced this issue and know how to prevent the error message from being triggered every time?

Here is an example:

`npm i webpack -g`

```
/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.1/bin/webpack -> /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.1/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js

> fsevents@1.2.11 install /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.1/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild
```

Then the Python is triggered:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:606:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.1/bin/node" "/Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.1/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/webpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

And finally the package install was successful:

```
+ webpack@4.41.4
added 1 package from 1 contributor, removed 1 package and updated 34 packages in 11.622s
```